# list checking in python

Tags: python, list

Hello there
i've written a small functions that takes two lists and compares them for duplicating pairs,
and returns a boolean value.

For instance ([1,2,3],[2,1,4]) returns false and ([1,2,3],[3,4,5]) returns true
But i would like the argument to take any given amount of lists, instead of just two.

Here's my program so far:

```
def check(xrr, yrr):
    x = xrr[:]
    x.sort()
    y = yrr[:]
    y.sort()
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[i]==y[i]:
            return False
    return True
```

But also it isnt exactly working correctly yet, as ([1,2,3],[1,4,5]) also returns false.

Any hints and ideas is highly appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "duplicating pairs"? Do you want to return True if there is any number that can be found in both lists? Or does it have to be in the same position in both lists? Or just what?

Comment: Why would you expect `([1,2,3],[1,4,5])` to return `False`? The first element in both after sorting is `1`, so `x[0]==y[0]`, and it *should* return false.  The question is, *what do you mean by* **duplicating pairs**?

Comment: @ A A, yeah youre excactly right, i noticed that as well, that's about to change!

Comment: What is the logic behind - [1,2,3],[2,1,4] returns False. And [1,2,3],[3,4,5] returns True?

Comment: about duplicating pairs, i mean that for instance [1,2,3],[2,1,4] has a duplicate pair: [1,2] but [1,2,3],[1,4,5] doesnt. I'll work some more on it :)

Comment: Do we count [1,5] as a duplicate pair between [1,2,5], [1,4,5]?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I posted a naive solution that compares elements from any set, looking for repeating elements. It should be possible to trivially refactor from there.

Comment: @Karl, yes that would also be duplicates

Comment: Then you have a duplicate pair as long as there are **two common elements** between the two sets, and I will write my answer accordingly. - Actually, no, I won't, because Kabie has done basically exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a naive implementation, you can define a list of lists and hash the internal representation. For instance:

```
def check(given):
   hash = {}
   for li in given:
      for val in li:
         if val in hash:
            return False
         hash[val] = 1
   return True
```

This works if your input data sets contain a small number of unique elements relative to memory. If you expect to receive extremely large data sets, you might need to consider a more elaborate approach.

Also notable is this will return `False` for repeating elements within the same data set, and for repeating values at any location within the data set. This is trivial to refactor, or to rewrite entirely as the other solutions listed here.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is more or less excactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: `has_key` is totally obsolete and deprecated. Use the `in` keyword. instead. This has the advantage of being much faster in Python 2 and available in Python 3.

Comment: @aaronasterling +1 for the reminder. Deprecated usage of `has_key` is a dirty habit carried forward from 2.3. I'll also point out that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374426/list-checking-in-python/4374531#4374531 is the more robust, more correct solution.

Comment: This is wrong isn't it? It will return `False` for any duplicate.

Comment: @aaronasterling Which is precisely what I call out. If a stronger or more correct answer is preferred, I'd be quite happy to delete this one. Assuming someone else doesn't, that is.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

def check(*args):
  r = None
  for l in args:
    s = set(frozenset(x) for x in itertools.combinations(l, 2))
    if r is None:
      r = s
    else:
      r &= s
    if not r:
      return True
  return False

print check([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])
print check([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 4])
```

Comment: +1. More robust, with interesting application of `itertools`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def dupLists(List0,*Lists):
    result=set(List0)
    for l in Lists:
        result=result.intersection(l)
        if len(result)<2:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: +1 for the right approach, but you appear to have the return values the wrong way around.

Comment: the return values seem right to me? However this only works on two lists, instead of any amount of lists

Comment: @user457142: It does works on any amount of lists(at least two). that's why I wrote it for.

Comment: but dupLists([1,2,3],[2,1,4]) returns false, which is correct, however dupLists([1,2,3],[2,1,4],[3,5,6]) returns true, which is not correct

Comment: Aha, that's because I misunderstood. This function return False only all the lists duplicated.